# nuxt load assets files when sidebar opened

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt application that has a sidebar navigation.
In mobile sidebar is closed for default and when click on menu sidebar will be opened with animation.
for first time this opening is laggy and after that is smooth.
I realize this laggy is because when sidebar opened, some assets files will load.

This is for before open sidebar(the css files only):
[image]

and this is for when I open sidebar:
[image]

These css files seem to be some of my pages that nuxt load them before I open that page.
In my sidebar component I just loop through items and use them in `<nuxt-link>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nuxt load bundle file when see `<nuxt-link>`. So you can programming change route to avoid this.
like:
`$router.push('/route')`